# Finding the solution to this MLE problem

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample of distribution with probability density function

$$f(x\mid\theta) = \theta x^{\theta-1},\quad 0\lt x \lt 1,\quad 0\lt \theta \lt \infty$$

how can i find MLE of parameter $θ$?

My working is like this:

$$L(\theta\mid x) = \prod f(x\mid\theta)
= \prod \theta x^{\theta-1} = \theta^n \prod x ^{\theta-1}$$

Then I got stuck...

Comment: "$\theta x\theta^{-1}$" doesn't make a lot of sense.  Can you explain what you intended here?

Comment: should look this way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\theta-1} = \left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^{\theta-1},
$$
so
$$
L(\theta) = \theta^n P^{\theta-1},
$$
where $P$ is the product.  Therefore
$$
\ell(\theta)=\log L(\theta) = n\log\theta + (\theta-1)\log P,
$$
so $\ell\,'(\theta) = \dfrac n\theta+\log P$, etc.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: can explain why the $\theta-1 $ was taken out?

Comment: Because $\log\left(P^{\theta-1}\right) = (\theta-1)\log P$, and differentiation is simple when it's in that form.

Comment: i mean the earlier one.. at the top...

Comment: Just so that the number of times the expression $\theta-1$ appears would be only one.  And for some other purposes, if not for the present problem, it is of interest to know that this function depends on the data only through the product of the $x$ values.

Comment: do u know how to show that it is consistent estimator for this as well?