# Finding the solution of MME Problem

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample of distribution with probability density function

$$f(x\mid\theta) = \theta x^{\theta-1},\quad 0\lt x \lt 1,\quad 0\lt \theta \lt \infty$$

how can i find MME of parameter $θ$?

My working:

$E[\theta x^{\theta-1}] = \bar X $

$\theta E[x^{\theta-1}]= \bar X$

$\theta = \bar X/E[x^{\theta-1}]$

Not sure whether this is correct.. Need some guidance on this...

Comment: If you mean MLE, then this is a duplicate of a question posted an hour or two ago. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483256/finding-the-solution-to-this-mle-problem

Comment: Or did you mean method of moments?

Comment: method of moments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working confuses random variables with numbers, and I suspect there is an error in the computation of the expectation. Note that, for every $k$,
$$
E_\theta[X_k]=\int xf_\theta(x) \, \mathrm dx=\int_0^1\theta x^\theta \, \mathrm dx=\frac\theta{\theta+1},
$$
hence the first moment estimator $\hat\theta$ based on $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ solves 
$$
\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k=\frac{\hat\theta}{\hat\theta+1},
$$
that is,
$$
\hat\theta=\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n-(X_1+\cdots+X_n)}.
$$